# Should I do fix skewness of the data before feature selection or after feature selection and choosing the best model using AIC/BIC?

Tags: r, python, skewness

So, I am trying to develop a linear regression model and I want to know whether it is a good decision to fix the skewness of the data before selecting the best features for the model or should I use AIC/BIC to see which features are best for prediction and then just fix the skewness of the data on those specific features. Right now I am doing Linear Regression but I want to know if it is the same for all the models. Thank you.

Comment: Fixing skewed features has to come before selection.

Comment: Why do you think skewness is a problem? Skewness of what? How do you intend to fix it?